# how to use and show percent in loader till ajax jquery function is busy executing

Tags: jquery

I want to show percent in loader till ajax function busy(load data). simple loader working but not able to count percent while get response. 
i have tried this code but its count percent when function execution completed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax ({
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: { strDate: startDate},
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //Load progress
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        document.getElementById("ShowPercent").innerText =  
                            Math.round(percentComplete * 100) + "%";
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },

         )};
});
```

Comment: Well, you can't. This code works best for file uploads since you can know the upload speed and file size. But there is no way to predict how long the server will take to run a certain task through a simple request.

Comment: Unless the server reports this information periodically, through web sockets. [pusher](http://pusher.io) is quite good for that. Easy API, though quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! 
Actually we are loading lots of data from service and its taking time so we want to this. 
Is there any other way, so i can use and show percent in loader, so user can see till progress showing in percent ....

Comment: @Hemant - like I say, use web sockets. These are non-trivial to do manually so look into something like Pusher.

Comment: Is there any custom way without hitting url again and again, anyone can help ?

Comment: Yes - look into Pusher! :) It's not hitting the URL again and again, it's a different technology, called web sockets.

Comment: Ok, I don't have idea about web sockets. could you please give me code sample so we can implement that in my system for my requirement.